# I'm having trouble with npm install for angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

This is error that I'm getting in cmd prompt:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
 > angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\hp\Desktop\angular2-seed
 > typings install

'typings' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall script 'typings install'.

npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\Desktop\angular2-seed\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: try to install typings first `npm install typings --global`

Comment: @maxisam now I'm getting this: C:\Users\hp\Desktop\angular2-seed>npm install

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\hp\Desktop\angular2-seed
> typings install


└── (No dependencies)

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.

Comment: I run npm start now and it is working, thanks a lot @maxisam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see

> 'typings' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program > or batch file.

try to install typings first `npm install typings --global`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install typings globally:
- `npm i typings -g`